# How to read value from Excel knowing that the address location can change

Tags: excel, vba

I want to retrieve a cell value from Excel, knowing that it's cell address can change in the future?

For example:
Today
[image]

```vb
coy = StrConv(Trim(Worksheets(WS_Setting).Range("B2").Value), vbProperCase)
director = StrConv(Trim(Worksheets(WS_Setting).Range("B3").Value), vbProperCase)
```

Tomorrow: items added, table shifted:
[image]

Is there VBA code that can get values if the table is shifted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your data has always the same row and column labels (eg "Director:" for row and "Shortname" for column), I would suggest to have a small function that searches for that labels and, if both are found, return the cell value that is defined by that row and column.

```
Function getTableValue(ws As Worksheet, rowLabel As String, colLabel As String) As String
    Dim row As Long, col As Long
    Dim rowRange As Range, colRange As Range
    Set rowRange = ws.UsedRange.Find(rowLabel)
    If rowRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Set colRange = ws.UsedRange.Find(colLabel)
    If colRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    getTableValue = ws.Cells(rowRange.row, colRange.Column)
End Function
```

Your code then simply looks like

```
coy = getTableValue(Worksheets(WS_Setting), "Company:", "ShortName")
director = getTableValue(Worksheets(WS_Setting), "Director:", "ShortName")
```

Comment: Clever & solid solution +:) fyi posted a class solution by intersection you might be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative via Class**

In order to be largely independent of moving cell addresses, you can also

- **name** all *cells with the reference headings manually* (instead of searching for possibly varying captions only) and
- use a **class** by means of a dictionary to record or read all named contents where the **core logic** is based on the *intersection* address of the row and column headings.

*This post does not claim to represent the simplest or most efficient solution - it is only intended to provide inspiration and can be adapted in any way.*

**Example call in a standard module**

```
Option Explicit
'Site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78056632/excel-vba-how-to-dynamically-read-value-from-excel-knowing-that-the-address-lo/78056719#78056719
Sub ExampleViaClass()
    Dim settings As cSettings
    Set settings = New cSettings
'a) display all related contents
    settings.DisplayAll
    ''  ~~> Company is Dell Tech P (Dell)
    ''  ~~> Director is Simon Rick (Sim)
    
'b) Example of single calls:
    Dim srch As String
    srch = "Director"
    
    Debug.Print "**Cell content of  '" & prop(srch) & "' is " & settings.Content(srch, 1)
    Debug.Print "**Cell name   for  '" & prop(srch) & "' is " & settings.CellName(srch)
    ''  ~~> **Cell content of  'Director' is Simon Rick
    ''  ~~> **Cell name   for  'Director' is rex
End Sub

Function prop(s)
    prop = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(s)
End Function
```

**Class module cSettings**

```
Option Explicit
'Site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78056632/excel-vba-how-to-dynamically-read-value-from-excel-knowing-that-the-address-lo/78056719#78056719
'Auth: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
Private ws As Worksheet
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set ws = Sheet1     ' << change to any other sheet CellName(Name)
    'alternatively:     '    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Sub

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'//core logic to get content
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Private Function getName(Label As Range, NameType As Range) As String
'Purp:  read value based on intersection of existing named cells (e.g. "coy" and "short")
    getName = Intersect(Label.EntireRow, NameType.EntireColumn).Text
End Function

Public Function CellName(ByVal what As String) As String
'Purp:  get Cell name of existing dictionary key (e.g. what:="company" ~~> "coy")
    If dict.Exists(LCase(what)) Then CellName = dict(LCase(what))
End Function

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'//main func content
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Public Function Content(ByVal what As String, Optional ByVal how = 0) As String
'Purp: pass user defined function arguments to final function getName
'Note: argument how:=0 .. short name; 1 .. full name
    On Error Resume Next
    Content = getName(ws.Range(CellName(what)), ws.Range(CellName(how)))
End Function
```

*.. further code in* **Class cSettings**

```
Public Function dict() As Dictionary
'Purp:  populate dictionary with Cell Names for cells with captions like Company, Director etc.
'Note:  assumes lower case keys
    Static d As Dictionary ' static: keep state across different calls
    If d Is Nothing Then
    'a) set dictionary to memory
        Set d = New Dictionary
    'b) populate dictionary
    '   ----- Key -----  CellName
        d.Add "company", "coy"
        d.Add "director", "rex"
        '..
        '..
    'c) numeric keys for type of display
        d.Add "0", "short"      ' ShortName
        d.Add "1", "full"       ' FullName
    End If
    Set dict = d
End Function

Public Sub DisplayAll()
'Purp:  display all contents
    Dim key
    For Each key In dict
        If Not IsNumeric(key) Then Debug.Print _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(key) & " is " & _
            Content(key, 1) & _
            " (" & Content(key) & ")"
    Next
End Sub
```